# prove that : $D_{4n} $ is isomorphic to $ D_{2n} \times Z_2 $ when $n$ is odd

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, examples-counterexamples

let $n$ be odd integer , prove that : $D_{4n} $ is isomorphic to $ D_{2n} \times Z_2 $

it's an example which the text proves ! but i can't understand any thing from the argument !

but i tried to prove it  by constructing the  isomorphism function directly 
but every time there was a tiny gap !so anyone knows nice proof fot this ?

Comment: How does your textbook prove the result? Also, what convention do you use for the dihedral group of order $n$; is it $D_n$ or $D_{2n}$?

Comment: Think geometrically... how can we see two copies of a shape with half as many vertices inside this one? Draw a picture of a hexagon, for example... do you see two triangles?

Comment: @AndrewD , i use $D_{2n}$ , the text define $H=(s,r^2) , K=(r^n)$ and use the theorem which says ,$ HK=H \times K$ if the intersection is trivial and they are both normal of the group ,also find a speech about centerlizar and ceter of $D_{4n}$

Comment: @DylanWilson, didn't understand ! more clarification plz?

Comment: Sketch out (roughly) a regular hexagon on a piece of paper, and draw (again roughly) an equilateral triangle inside of it. Then cut it out, and just experiment which some of the rotations involved. That should help a bit to allow you to see what is geometrically going on, as certainly the geometric perspective is the easiest way of proving this result.

Comment: @BabakS. it's first time which i see $D_{4n}$ in the text ! but i'm quite familiar with $D_{2n}$ .

Comment: @MathsLover: Are above $H$ and $K$ supposed to be subgroups of $D_{2n}$ or $D_{4n}$ in your text?

Comment: @BabakS. , they are subgroups of $D_{4n}$.

Comment: @MathsLover: Well, I think you can write down the presentation of $D_{4n}$ firstly and then see that the relations in it allow you to find out why these two subgroups are normal in $D_{4n}$.

Comment: @BabakS. , i think i got the idea of the proof now! it's understood  :D thank you all :)

Comment: @MathsLover: So we will be waiting for a concrete proof. An +1 for the question as well. :)

Comment: @BabakS. , i tried to prove it by constructing a isomorphism between them but every time there is a tiny gap which don't make it surjective or homomorphism , i think some trial and erroe process can enable me to get the right function ! i will try again :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $Z_n\times Z_2\cong Z_{2n}$ if $n$ is odd and the inveres of $(x,y)\in Z_n\times Z_2$ is $(-x,y)$, that is we have an operation of $Z_2$ on $Z_{2n}$ by inversion that boils down to the trivial operation on the summand $Z_2$ and again inversion on $Z_n$. Therefore 
$$ D_{4n}\cong Z_{2n}\rtimes Z_2\cong(Z_n\times Z_2)\rtimes Z_2\cong(Z_n\rtimes Z_2)\times Z_2\cong D_{2n}\times Z_2.$$

Comment: seems to be nice proof ! i will read it when i reach semidirect product - next section on my text , not so far :)) - thanx

Answer (score 3):

Hagen's proof is great, and certainly more generalizable (a great advertisement for semidirect products).

In this particular case, however, it may be more intuitive to see what's going on...

If we have an even-sided regular polygon, say with $2n$ sides, then we may form a regular polygon inside it by connecting every other vertex, in turn. Actually, we can form two such, by offsetting by one. Doing this with a hexagon should produce a familiar star-shape, which can also be found, for example, on the Israeli flag ;)

Now, pick one of these $n$-gons. Any symmetry of the $2n$-gon either sends this $n$-gon to itself (in which case it is a symmetry of the $n$-gon), or else sends it to the other $n$-gon (possibly with a symmetry applied). This gives a map $D_{4n} \rightarrow D_{2n} \times C_2$. Now note that once you've said where the $n$-gon goes you've *uniquely* determined a symmetry of the $2n$-gon, so this map is bijective.

Comment: +1 for the clear geometric picture, but I think one should elaborate a little more on the map being a homomorphism of groups.

Comment: @Dylan Wilson , why being the $n$-gon sended to itself or to the other $n$-gon gives us this function ?also what about being onto ? and homomorphism ?